# We have $8$ males and $7$ females. In how many ways can $7$ couples (husband and wife) be created?

Tags: permutations, combinations

We have $8$ males and $7$ females. In how many ways can $7$ couples (husband and wife) be created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider matching the "first" female with one of the males. There are 8 choices. Similarly, for the second female, you're left with 7 choices. Proceeding in this manner, you see that the total number of ways should simply equal $8\times 7\times 6\times\cdots\times 2=8!$.